# Multiplying large number of pandas column to each other

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1      4        6
2      5        7
3      6        8
```

I want to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Mult
1       4       6       24
2       5       7       70
3       6       8       144
```

where `df['Mult'] = df['Col1']*df['Col2']*df['Col3']`

Except in my case I have about 50 columns Col1, Col2, ..Col50.

So, using the following method is going to be very tedious `df['col1'].multiply(df['Col2'], axis=1)`

Is there a faster way? I am trying to avoid using the `apply` method for each row as I think that will be very slow as my dataframe has about 1 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1,2,3],
                  "Col2":[4,5,6],
                  "Col3":[6,7,8]})

df["Mult"] = df.prod(1)
```

**Output:**

```
df

    Col1    Col2    Col3    Mult
0   1       4       6       24
1   2       5       7       70
2   3       6       8       144
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html):

```
df['Mult'] = df.prod(1)
```

Or if a subset of columns:

```
df['Mult'] = df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].prod(1)
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Mult
0     1     4     6    24
1     2     5     7    70
2     3     6     8   144
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `np.prod`:

```
df['Mult'] = np.prod(df, axis=1)
```